# How to set the precision of JsNumber output in spray.json?

Tags: spray-json

The data I work with has a fixed 5 digits of precision. I'd like to enforce this when generating the JsNumber's so that i.e. floating point inaccuracies would not generate any .123450000000000001 output, ever.

Is this possible? I haven't found out a way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom `JsonWriter` to do this (within your protocol or wherever else with a higher-precedence implicit scope):

```
implicit object RoundedDoubleJsonWriter extends JsonWriter[Double] {
  def write(d: Double) =
    JsNumber(BigDecimal(d).setScale(4, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
}
```

Change the rounding mode/method to taste.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But it took me some hours to realize this only works for `Double` if you use `Float` the precision goes away. Thanks.